# How to get HttpVersion from HttpResponse

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-middleware

Is there a way to get the HttpVersion from the `HttpResponse`?  I know I can get it by pulling the `IHttpRequestFeature` and looking at `.Protocol`, but that's what's sent in via the request.  Will that always match what's sent back for the response?

I'm trying to get the full message that's sent back for logging purposes.  I can get the headers and the message, but getting the `HTTP/1.1` from the response is what I'm missing.

Comment: Did you try this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.protocolversion%28v=vs.110%29.aspx ?

Comment: @Alex:  That's on the client; is there something equivalent on the server?

Comment: The request sent to the server is for a specific resource using a certain protocol version. If it can be found and you get a successful response, it means that the version can be found from the request.

Comment: @JohanP:  So the protocol version of the response will always match the protocol version of the request?  If I get in `HTTP/1.1`, I will always respond with `HTTP/1.1`, since that's what's been requested as the supported communication version?  That makes a lot of sense; I'm just verifying.

Comment: Yes. If a client request HTTP/1.1 the server is not going to respond with a h2 for example.

Comment: @JohanP:  Thank you!

Comment: It is called a protocol. It is something that client and server agree on it before they get started. As already mentioned, if request is made with 1.1 then response will always match it. There is one caveat in .NET though. If you make the request with http/2 to a webapp running on a Windows machine, `request.Version` will always say `1.1` due to how things are handled in Windows through http.sys.